# A 2nd order nonlinear ODE with one boundary and two algebrac equation constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

How to solve the following nonlinear ODE with two algebraic equations and one  boundary condition?

$$y''(x)=\dfrac{2\left((x+15)y'(x)-y(x)\right)\left(y'(x)^2+1\right)}{\left(y(x)^2+x(x+30)+236\right)^2}$$

The boundary condition:
$$y(-14)=0$$

The algebraic equation constraint:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 y(x_0)=\sqrt{1-x_0^2} &\\[15pt]
 y'(x_0)=\dfrac{-x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2}}& \text{where: }-1\lt x_0\lt 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: If you want the solution curve tangent to the unit circle, the derivative condition should be $y'(x_0)=(\sqrt{1-x_0^2})'=\frac{-x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2}}$.

Comment: thank you! It's a typo. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that depends on $x_0$ to integrate from $x_0$ to $-14$ using the given formulas as initial conditions and returns the value $y(-14)$. Use the secant method, or some bracketed method to be sure to stay in the interval, to find the value of $x_0$ that gives $y(-14)=0$.

---

The following code gives the tangency to the unit circle at $x_0=-0.0716992989368$, $y(-14)=3.17161661517·10^{-15}$, $y'(-14)=0.0699203372635$. One could replace the fixed step classical Runge-Kutta with one of `scipy-odeint` or `scipy-ode`, but that should only change little in the result.

```
import numpy as np

def odefunc(x,y):
    u,v = y
    # y''(x)=[ 2((x+15)y'(x)-y(x))(y'(x)^2+1) ] / [ (y(x)^2+x(x+30)+236)^2 ]
    return [ v, ( 2*((x+15)*v-u)*(v**2+1) ) / ( (u**2+x*(x+30)+236)**2 ) ];


def odeint(f,t0,y0,tf,h):
    '''Classical RK4 with fixed step size, modify h to fit
    the full interval'''
    N = np.ceil( (tf-t0)/h )
    h = (tf-t0)/N

    t = t0
    y = np.array(y0)
    for k in range(int(N)):
        k1 = h*np.array(f(t      ,y       ))
        k2 = h*np.array(f(t+0.5*h,y+0.5*k1))
        k3 = h*np.array(f(t+0.5*h,y+0.5*k2))
        k4 = h*np.array(f(t+    h,y+    k3))
        y = y + (k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6
        t = t + h
    return t, y

def objective(x0):
    '''integrate a ray tangential to the unit circle 
    to x=-14, return y value'''
    y0 = [ np.sqrt(1-x0**2), -x0/np.sqrt(1-x0**2) ]
    t, y = odeint(odefunc, x0, y0, -14.0, -0.01)
    print x0,t,y
    return y[0]

def illinois(f,a,b):
    '''regula falsi resp. false postion method with
    the Illinois anti-stalling variation'''
    fa = f(a)
    fb = f(b)
    while(np.abs(b-a)>1e-10):
        c = (a*fb-b*fa)/(fb-fa)
        fc = f(c)
        if fa*fc < 0:
            fa *= 0.5
        else:
            a = b; fa = fb
        b = c; fb = fc
    return b, fb

# function value table, inconsequential for solution of the problem
# for k in range(21):
#     objective(-0.99+(0.99*k)/20)
#     
# print "--------------"

x,y = illinois(objective, -0.5,0)
print x,y
```

Comment: Can it be a little more detailed and with a solution (numerical one)?

Comment: I'm sure it is expected that you do the work. Using fast'n'dirty Euler +regula falsi I get a solution at about $x_0=-0.07151$.

Comment: It would help if you could indicate what the background for this problem is, with those initial conditions it _looks_ like homework.

Comment: It has a physical background, see this link: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170142/how-to-calculate-desired-light-path-in-continuous-medium-with-gradient-refractio

Comment: Though my python knowledge is still limited, I think I now can understand the strategy you're using: try different $x_0$ points until the iteration obtain desired error tolerance. -- Actually, I did expect a direct method to handle such "combined Dirichlet and Neumann  undetermined boundary" for nonlinear ODE,though it looks difficult. In the physics.stackexchange link, the calculation I was using is also by iteration, but I was expecting some direct method. Thank you, the answer is definitely acceptable.

Comment: This sounds like the multiple-shooting strategy (in contrast to the single-shooting employed above) for ODE-BVP. One further step in the subdivision direction would lead to finite-element methods. But since single-shooting works well, there is no reason to employ the more complicated methods.

Comment: When solving such ODE, I usually use the Mathematica/matlab/maple solvers. therefore my basic knowledge on the ODE theory is limited, not to say programming such a solver. I will try to learn if related keywords are given. thank you for kind guidance.

Comment: By all means, you can use such solvers. The only thing that you have to program yourself is `odefunc` and `objective`. Use the supplied solvers for the ODE and for non-linear equations. What the above shows is that the code behind these need not be very complicated (for scalar problems).

Comment: thank you! what made me feel urgent to learn more about differential equations is that, usually I meet nonlinear differential equations which cannot be or cannot easily be solved by those open sourced or commercial solvers. e.g., I am also being stumbled by understanding an already solved  nonlinear PDE problem by "method of lines": http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104464/problems-when-solving-a-nonlinear-pde-system-with-ndsolve